How to get AmountOut of a swap on RAYDIUM SOLANA please?
Hello how can i calcul amountOut of a swap on solana raydium please ?
This is the code i try :
import RaydiumSwap from './RaydiumSwap'
import { Transaction, VersionedTransaction, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL } from '@solana/web3.js'
import { Connection, PublicKey,} from "@solana/web3.js";
import { LiquidityPoolKeys,LiquidityPoolKeysV4, Liquidity, TokenAmount, Token, Percent, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, SPL_ACCOUNT_LAYOUT,  TokenAccount } from "@raydium-io/raydium-sdk";

 async function calcAmountOut(connection: Connection, poolKeys: LiquidityPoolKeys, rawAmountIn: number, swapInDirection: boolean)  {
  console.log('im here');

  const raydiumSwap = new RaydiumSwap('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com', '3onho4yEyCL8wh6v644YvkTmPVg000000000000000000000Y5Z6oHJCqDUM3NZY6KNyqy4kDHeDCwxk')
  const poolInfo = await Liquidity.fetchInfo({
  connection: raydiumSwap.connection,
  poolKeys: poolKeys,
});

  let currencyInMint = poolKeys.baseMint;
  console.log(currencyInMint);
  
  let currencyInDecimals = poolInfo.baseDecimals;
  let currencyOutMint = poolKeys.quoteMint;
  let currencyOutDecimals = poolInfo.quoteDecimals;

  if (!swapInDirection) {
      currencyInMint = poolKeys.quoteMint;
      currencyInDecimals = poolInfo.quoteDecimals;
      currencyOutMint = poolKeys.baseMint;
      currencyOutDecimals = poolInfo.baseDecimals;
  }

  const currencyIn = new Token(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, currencyInMint, currencyInDecimals);
  const amountIn = new TokenAmount(currencyIn, rawAmountIn, false);
  const currencyOut = new Token(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, currencyOutMint, currencyOutDecimals);
  const slippage = new Percent(0, 100); // 5% slippage

  const { amountOut, minAmountOut, currentPrice, executionPrice, priceImpact, fee } = Liquidity.computeAmountOut({
      poolKeys,
      poolInfo,
      amountIn,
      currencyOut,
      slippage,
  });

  return {
      amountIn,
      amountOut,
      minAmountOut,
      currentPrice,
      executionPrice,
      priceImpact,
      fee,
  };
}
calcAmountOut;

But actually my code return absolutly nothing when i run it :(

Up we need help please

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try adding a try-catch block to your code and console log the error. It will show the exact error that is happening.
